# How to redirect to login page for restricted pages in next.js?

Tags: firebase, authentication, redirect, next.js, server-side-rendering

In the udemy tutorial [The Complete React Developer Course](https://www.udemy.com/course/react-2nd-edition/) the additional package [history](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history) was used to get the router outside a component for redirecting when the user is not authenticated:

```
/* AppRouter.js */
import createHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory";

const AppRouter = () => (
    <Router history={history}>
      <div>
        <Switch>
            <PublicRoute path="/" component={LoginPage} exact={true} />
            <PrivateRoute
                path="/dashboard"
                component={ExpenseDashboardPage}
            />
            <PrivateRoute path="/create" component={AddExpensePage} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/edit/:id" component={EditExpensePage} />
            <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
);

export default AppRouter;



/* PrivateRouter.js */
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "../components/Header";

export const PrivateRoute = ({
    isAuthenticated,
    component: Component,
    ...rest
}) => (
    <Route
        {...rest}
        component={(props) =>
            isAuthenticated ? (
                <div>
                    <Header />
                    <Component {...props} />
                </div>
            ) : (
                <Redirect to="/" />
            )
        }
    />
);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isAuthenticated: !!state.auth.uid
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

The code for `app.js` is as follows:

```
/* app.js */
import AppRouter, { history } from "./routers/AppRouter";

const store = configureStore();

const jsx = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <AppRouter />
    </Provider>
);

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
        store.dispatch(login(user.uid));
        store.dispatch(startSetExpenses()).then(() => {
            if (history.location.pathname === "/") {
                history.push("/dashboard");
            }
        });
    } else {
        store.dispatch(logout());
        history.push("/");
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(jsx, document.getElementById("app"));
```

My question now is, how can I achieve this in my next.js project? I have tried a kind of similar way in the `_app.js` file. Can I accomplish this behavior somehow with the `getInitialProps` routine? In the zeit/next example [with-firebase-authentication](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-firebase-authentication) I have seen a combination of `getInitialProps` and `componentDidMount`, but was not successful to implement it in this way.

```
import withRedux from 'next-redux-wrapper';
import App from 'next/app';
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { firebase } from '../src/firebase/firebase';
import reduxStore from '../src/redux/store';

class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log('log in');
      } else {
        if (ctx.isServer && ctx.req.url !== '/login') {
          ctx.res.writeHead(302, { Location: '/login' });
          ctx.res.end();
        }
        console.log('log out');
      }
    });

    return {
      pageProps: Component.getInitialProps
        ? await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
        : {}
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps, store } = this.props;

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

// firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
//   if (user) {
//     console.log('log in');
//   } else {
//     // router instance not accessible!
//     Router.push("/login");
//     console.log('log out');
//   }
// });

export default withRedux(reduxStore, { debug: false })(MyApp);
```

Answer (score 14):

```js
import Router from "next/router";

export function redirectUser(ctx, location) {
  if (ctx.req) {
    ctx.res.writeHead(302, { Location: location });
    ctx.res.end();
  } else {
    Router.push(location);
  }
}

class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    const { token } = parseCookies(ctx);

    let pageProps = {};

    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);
    }

    // Restrict unauthorized user
    if (!token) {
      const isProtectedRoute =
        ctx.pathname === "/account" || ctx.pathname === "/create";

      if (isProtectedRoute) {
        redirectUser(ctx, "/signin");
      }
    }
    else {
      try {
         // Restrict user based on role on certain page
        const user;
        const isRoot = user.role === "root";
        const isAdmin = user.role === "admin";
        const isNotPermitted =
          !(isRoot || isAdmin) && ctx.pathname === "/create";

        if (isNotPermitted) {
          redirectUser(ctx, "/");
        }

        pageProps.user = user;
      }
      catch (err) {
        console.error("Error getting current user", err);

        destroyCookie(ctx, "token");
        redirectUser(ctx, "/signin");
      }
    }

    return { ...pageProps };
  }
}
```